# Assigning double variables to dynamic double array

Tags: c++, coding-style, windows-console

I tried to assign different variables value to double array in loop but the whole array has just 1 value

```
double *float_array;
float_array = new double [dynamic_variable]; // debugger does tell me its size     
stringstream ss1(line);

string s1;
string s2 = "2.1";
double test= atof(s2.c_str());
while (getline(ss1,s1,','))
{
    float_array[count] = atof(s1.c_str());
    count++;
}
count = 0;
root->data = float_array;
root->next = new node;
```

showing some more code

```
class node
{

public:
     double * data;
    node *next;
    node(void);
    ~node(void);
};

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    double arr[4]= {0.689997};
    double * float_array;
    string file_name; 
    string line,token;
    string path= "D:\\DM\\Assignment No. 1\\";
    cin>>file_name;
     file_name= path + file_name;
     ifstream aa;
     aa.open(file_name,ios::in|ios::out);
     node *root; int float_arr_size=0;int count=0;
     //aa.open(file_name,ios::in|ios::out);
     if(aa.is_open())
     {

        while(!aa.eof())
        {
            aa>>line;
            cout<<line<<endl;
            cout<<endl;
            stringstream ss(line);
            string s;

            while (getline(ss, s, ','))
            {
            float_arr_size++;
            }

            float_array= new double[float_arr_size];
            s="";

            stringstream ss1(line);
            string s1;
            string s2= "2.1";
            double test= atof(s2.c_str());
            while(getline(ss1,s1,','))
            {
                float_array[count] =  atof(s1.c_str());
                count++;
            }
            count = 0;
            root->data =float_array;
            root->next= new node;
        }
     }
    aa.close();

    return 0;
}
```

I get perfect conversion in my test variable. I also get "2.1" in `s1`, but in debugger I get only one value in float_array that is  5.0999945.  No further indexes have any further values.  After having test variable value converted correctly, I see problem in my dynamic array.

Is there a solution, please?

Comment: Where do you initialise `count`?

Comment: Is `count` initialized before the beginning of this snippet? What does `line` contain?

Comment: so what is the question? why it is 5.09999 and not 5.1 ?

Comment: the float_array only shows one index in debugger , the value of dynamic_variable taken from file is 4 in first iteration from file and its stored in int

Comment: line = "5.1,2.1,3.6,4.8"

Comment: @sparkling_spark The debugger does not know the size of an array created with `new[]`. You should instead write a loop to print the contents, or look deeper into your debugger and manually tell it the size.

Comment: Assuming you are using VS, VS debugger shows only the first element in the array. If you want to see further index use quick watch with the required index.

Comment: You don't show the declaration or initialization of `count`.  The allocation of `float_array` should part of its declaration.  You don't show what's in `ss1` before you start operations.  You don't show the printing of `s1` in the loop.  You don't show the type information for `root`, but those two statements are unlikely to be material to your problem.

Comment: @Naveen I did , it show only one index

Comment: @sparkling_spark: See, your code works: http://ideone.com/SKd1L . You need to rely less on the debugger and/or familiarize yourself better with it.

Comment: @Potatoswatter  you are awesome , actually shifting from C# to C++ is creating troubles , I am making a win32 console app,

Comment: @Potatoswatter please post it as answer , I wana mark it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code [already works](http://ideone.com/SKd1L). C and C++ are low-level languages in a way that tends to hide information from the debugger, but the information still appears with `std::cout <<`.

Combine that with the possibility of bugs that depend on optimizations that may make the debugger all but useless, and it's a good idea to verify program functionality without special tools. A little off topic for this question, but it might help explain the general orientation of the community.

Answer (score 1):

Further to comments about the debugger not showing the whole array, in visual studio debugger for C/C++ you can add a watch like:

```
float_array,30
```

This will show you 30 elements of the array. Bear in mind this is not dynamic, and it will happily show you 30 elements of an array of length != 30 so you have to know the length of the array some other way and modify the watch as desired. If you want more 'friendly' debugger behaviour you can use std::vector. In fact, you probably should use std::vector anyway unless you really *enjoy* manual memory management.

*Edit: OK I noticed the word 'assignment' in the comments so maybe you are being forced to use manual memory management :)*

Answer (score 0):

Well, the only problem I see on your code is that you never store the amount of items you put in float_array, so I don't see how you can determine that later.

Because of the way pointers work on C++, most debuggers, when asked for a double*, will only show yo the first item of the array. Actually, there is no way for the debugger to know if that pointer is pointing to a single item or to an array (and if it's a dinamically created array, how many items it is comprised of)... and that's what I have experienced with the Visual Studio and Eclipse CDT debuggers. But your data should be there, try entering on your debugger (or printing to the console) the value in float_array[1], or in float_array[2].

Comment: thanks for guidance ,i edited my question now , with full code , i just shifted from C# to C++